# CRAFT CMS 3 loop matrix field - variable entry does not exist

Tags: loops, matrix, craftcms

I'm trying to loop a matrix field that has one block containing 3 items.

```
{% for block in entry.galeria.type('itemsGaleria') %}
{% if block.titulo|length %}
    {{ block.titulo.first }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But craft always throws the error variable entry does not exist.

I read the matrix section from craft 3 docs but cannot fix this problem.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as there where no sugestions, and i never give up, i figured out for myself :)

Here it is:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section("galeria").all() %}
{% for entry in entries %}
{% for block in entry.galeriaMatrix.all() %}
{% switch block.type %}
{% case "itemsGaleria" %}
{% for image in block.fotografia %}
    <img src="{{image.url}}" alt="{{image.title}}" />
{% endfor %}
{{ block.titulo }}
{{ block.texto }}
{% default %}
{% endswitch %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

It does what i need, which is loop all the entrances in the matrix block field.